# bazel compile error: linux/magic.h: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

```
ERROR: /ban/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/bazel-0.5.1-dist/src/main/cpp/BUILD:7:1: C++ compilation of rule '//src/main/cpp:blaze_util' failed: gcc failed: error executing command
(cd /tmp/bazel_tC149834/out/execroot/bazel-0.5.1-dist && 
exec env - 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/gcc-4.8.1/lib:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/gcc-4.8.1/lib64/:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/mpc-0.8.1/lib:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/gmp-4.3.2/lib:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/mpfr-2.4.2/lib:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/isl-0.11/lib:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/cloog-0.18.0/lib 
PATH=/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/binutils-2.28:/sc10/ap/sivl/2005.09-SP1-1/bin:/vol0/sys/myPrint/print_execd-6.2u4/bin/lx24-amd64:/sc10/ap/linux/bin:/ban/yohchang/:.:/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/dt/bin:/usr/openwin/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/ucb/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/sc10/ap/xv/sun:/ban/wchuang/tool:/sc10/ap/tool:/vol0/sys/tool:/usr/bin:/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/gcc-4.8.1/bin 
PWD=/proc/self/cwd 
/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/gcc-4.8.1/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -fstack-protector -Wall -B/volp1/quota_ctrl/yohchang/practice/tensorflow/local_install/gcc-4.8.1/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections '-std=c++0x' -MD -MF bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/cpp/objs/blaze_util/src/main/cpp/blaze_util_linux.d '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/cpp/objs/blaze_util/src/main/cpp/blaze_util_linux.o' -DBLAZE_OPENSOURCE -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote bazel-out/local-opt/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"' '-D__TIME__="redacted"' -c src/main/cpp/blaze_util_linux.cc -o bazel-out/local-opt/bin/src/main/cpp/_objs/blaze_util/src/main/cpp/blaze_util_linux.o): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
src/main/cpp/blaze_util_linux.cc:18:25: fatal error: linux/magic.h: No such file or directory
#include "linux/magic.h"
^
compilation terminated.
```

Don't really know how to solve this...
I try to use google to find some information. It tells me that maybe this problem is caused by my old kernel. But I don't really know what I can do next.

Environment info

Operating System:
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)
ldd (GNU libc) 2.5
gcc-4.8.1 (I install this compiler additionally.)
other information:
I can't use yum or any other on-line update to install package...
So I download source code and compile them on my redhat computer.

Bazel version (output of bazel info release):
0.5.1-dist
If you need any other information, please let me know!
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux/magic.h is not part of Bazel, it's part of the environment. I, for example, have it in `/usr/include/linux/magic.h`.

Can you download the equivalent of `kernel-headers` (the ones you would install by `yum install kernel-headers`) and put them somewhere gcc can see them? That would be into one of the directories returned by `gcc -E -xc++ - -v`.